# Can Microsoft DPM 2010 Backup Windows Server 2012 R2?

Tags: backup, scdpm, system-center

I have Microsoft DPM 2010 running on Server 2008 R2.

I wish to backup Server 2012 R2.

There is loose reference that this won’t work. Can anyone confirm if this is possible?

If so, are there any version requirements or prerequisites.

Comment: According to this link yes, if you have SP1+ for DPM 2010. I have no experience with it though, so not putting it as an answer. http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f347280e-d5bf-4020-9aa8-0b09b0fc1d3a/can-dpm-2012-back-up-windows-server-2012-with-deduplication?forum=dataprotectionmanager

Comment: I read your link as "DPM 2010 is not supported or working with Windows Server 2012." I believe your statement to be correct for DPM 2012 SP1 tho.

Comment: FWIW, Server 2012 is not in the [list of officially supported protected operating systems](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/ff399140.aspx) for DPM 2010.